# any of (double equal)== text in output doesnt print. it only prints output of boolean

Tags: java

dooble equals SOP is not getting output of text its only output boolean. I am using     jdk1.7.0_79

```
class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String s4 = new String("check"); 
        Thread t = new Thread();

        System.out.println(" s4== t " + t == s4); 
    }
}
```

expected output:      `s4==t false`
actual is:            `false`

Comment: The `t==s4` comparison will always return false, so it's pointless (even if you wrap it in parentheses).

Comment: what are you expecting as boolean result from comparing a Thread object against a String one.?????

Comment: `System.out.println(" s4== t "+t==s4); ` prints `System.out.println(("s4== t "+t)==s4); `, which is `false`

Comment: Your expression is interpreted as `("s4 == t" + t) == s4` which is just `false`. Doing `"s4 == t" + (t == s4)` doesn't really help because it doesn't compile. You could however do `Object s4=new String("check"); Object t=new Thread(); System.out.println(" s4== t "+(t == s4));` which would indeed give the output you expect.

Comment: How it works by changing Object instead of String and Thread i.e      Object s4=new String("check"); Object t=new Thread(); please explain

Comment: It helps because the compiler thinks it's plain silly to try to compare strings and threads, so it refuses to accept it. Comparing `Object` and `Object` seems ok to the compiler though, so that goes through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence of the `+` operator is higher than `==` in java.

So the expression `" s4 == t " + t == s4` will be evaluated as `("s4 == t " + t) == s4` which is `false`.

Additionally, `Thread` and `String` are incomparable types. so even if you change it to

```
System.out.println((" s4 == t " ) + (t == s4));
```

you'll get a compilation error complaining about that.

Finally, this will give you the result you desire:

```
System.out.println((" s4 == t " ) + (t.toString() == s4));
```